# get api data from $q

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

in my controller the code is written as calling an service "regionService"

```
.controller('RegionController', function( $scope , regionService) {
    $scope.RegionData=[];
    var promise = regionService.getRegionDetail();
    promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.RegionData = data.data;
        $scope.RegionDataStatus = data.status;
        debugger;
        console.log($scope.RegionData);
    });
})
```

code is written as Service

```
.service('regionService',function($http , $q){
    debugger;
    var deferred =$q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/getRegion').then( function(data)
    {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getRegionDetail = function()
    {
        return deferred.promise;
    };
})
```

and api json data is comes according AS

```
$scope.regionDetails =[
    {   "RegionName": "Asia",           "Regioncode": "ASIA"        },
    {   "RegionName": "South Asia",     "Regioncode": "SASI"        },
    {   "RegionName": "North Asia",     "Regioncode": "NASI"        },
    {   "RegionName": "West Asia",      "Regioncode": "WsASI"       },
    {   "RegionName": "EAst Asia",      "Regioncode": "EASI"        }
];
```

when we call service using Controller then as per deugger on console we get data  from API but after loading the page "$q" promise is override the Scope Varriable with null data Refrence becouse they call asynchronus $q promises

Comment: what are you getting in  `console.log($scope.RegionData);` ?

Comment: Does moving the api call into the function help? ie, something like this - 

this.getRegionDetail = function()
{
     var deferred =$q.defer();

      $http.get('/api/getRegion').then( function(data)
      {
       deferred.resolve(data);
      });
 return deferred.promise;
        };

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: i have got data from api on Page loading after all method is load then Q promise is call after that and then they override the result of data      $scope.regionDetails =[
    {   "RegionName": "Asia",           "Regioncode": "ASIA"        },
    {   "RegionName": "South Asia",     "Regioncode": "SASI"        },
    {   "RegionName": "North Asia",     "Regioncode": "NASI"        },
    {   "RegionName": "West Asia",      "Regioncode": "WsASI"       },
    {   "RegionName": "EAst Asia",      "Regioncode": "EASI"        }
    ];

Comment: dear JB Nizet        i am calling an api. they get some data in json format when page loading they call controller and service method as per rule of angular. they get json data on method loaing or calling but after all method is load then $q Promise is calling and then they override the varriable of data. I have checked in console with the help of debugger.